# Regex replace for commas in the thousands

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Javascript function I'm using to loop through a bunch of inputs on a page and convert them to a thousands-compatible comma system. In short, regardless of what the user types into the field, they'll get a friendly thousands-separated number back.

```
Input: 5000
Return: 5,000
```

**Here's how the function breaks down**

```
function add_commas()
{
    $('.field-group .field input[type=text]').each(function()
    {
        // format number
        $(this).val(function(index, value) {
            return value
            .replace(/\D/g, "")
            .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
            ;
        });
    });
}
```

Everything's working right except for one thing. Here's another example of the data being passed in and what's returned:

```
Input: 9.5
Return: 95
```

Note the whole number.

I'm wondering if there's a way to ignore or leave off the decimal if it didn't have one, but keep it and treat it respectfully if there is one. Here's the input/output as I would hope for:

```
Input: 5000
Return: 5,000

Input: 9.5
Return: 9.5

Input: 1000.50
Return: 1,000.50
```

Hopefully this was clear, but please do let me know if you require more information about the issue at hand. Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't this `.replace(/\D/g, "")` be `.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "")`

Comment: I think you should use `toLocaleString` instead

Answer (score 2):

Change the first replace because it is removing the dot in the string

```
.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm once you updated your comment. This is perfectly working now. Thank you so much! Saved my bacon tonight :)

Comment: Won't the resulting function put commas to the right of the decimal place? E.g., "1234.5678" gets formatted as "1,234.5,678".

Comment: @nnnnnn of course. "Never trust user input". I was simply pointing out an error in his logic. The issue was truncated decimals. I believe the correct solution is `(+value).toLocaleString()`

Answer (score 2):

Actually regular expressions are not appropriate for this problem, because not every culture uses commas as thousands separators and periods for the radix separator. You should be using `toLocaleString`. In node, for example:

```
> (52342.214).toLocaleString()
'52,342.214'
> (52342.214).toLocaleString('de-DE')
'52.342,214'
> (52342.214).toLocaleString('ar-EG')
'٥٢٬٣٤٢٫٢١٤'
> (5234289877.21).toLocaleString('en-US')
'5,234,289,877.21'
```

This way you don't have to write your own error-prone code and you can localize for different cultures. The work has already been done for you!

You also get the zeros part of your question for free too! Notice:

```
> (38209).toLocaleString()
'38,209'
> (38209.0000).toLocaleString()
'38,209'
```

Again, all for free!

Comment: This is an interesting approach to the problem, and I'll be researching how to incorporate it for our application. Appreciate this tip Ray! Thank you.

Comment: I was going to add it to my answer, but I think you should consider an answer that has string as an input instead of number i.e. convert value from string to int `(value | 0).toLocaleString()`

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that the set of locales supported by a given installation may differ from browser or browser and from system to system. So while it is the _correct_ approach to formatting user-displayable content (we should always consider usability and accessibility etc.), you do need to be pragmatic and make sure that all your users will benefit.

Comment: @JayHarris, indeed, a good note....or even `+value` to coerce to a number.